# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How I can show that the following series is divergent $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}?$$
thank in advance.

Comment: Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 4):

Following Stirling, $$ n!\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$
hence your series is comparable to $\sum\frac1{\sqrt n}$, which is divergent.

---

Without Stirling available, we consider
$$e^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{n^k}{k!}}_{=:a_k}$$
(where all summands are positive). For $k\ge n$, we have
$ \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{n}{k+1}\le \frac n{n+1}=:q$. As $q<1$, we can estimate the tail of the series by a geometric series:
$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n\le a_n\cdot\left(1+q+q^2+q^3+\ldots \right)=a_n\cdot\frac1{1-q}=(n+1)a_n.$$
On the other hand, for $k<n$ we have $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{n}{k+1}\ge1$, so that
$$\begin{align}e_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k+\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k\\&\le na_n+(n+1)a_n \end{align}$$
We conclude 
$$\frac{n^n}{n!e^n} =\frac{a_n}{e^n}\ge \frac1{2n+1}$$
and hence 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: Nice approach; I would have expected this to be too blunt, but it just barely isn't.